# Eclipse Android setting up a test project

Tags: android, eclipse, junit, project

I added a Test project to my main project like it's shown [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html#TestProjectPaths).
However, when I try to right click and go New -> Class to add a test class, the src folder is set to my main projects source folder, and the package is set to my main projects' package, and the test/ folder doesn't show up when I click on browse.

How do I set the test directory up properly, in Eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click on new class, you get the popup window, where you can set the new package name. (If you're not looking for this, then you should try out new thing below).

You can click on the package(which was created when you made new project), right click that package, then go new and new class to set up properly.

I hope this answer's your question.

Comment: Apparently I was being dumb and just typing out the whole name worked. Also, to actually run the test project, I had to import the project as  a new project into the workspace. Eclipse really does not make sense.